# Ставится ли в данном случае запятая между частями союза "несмотря на то(,) что"? Почему?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

"Тем не менее, говорить о беспрекословной безукоризненности протестантов не приходится: несмотря на то **(,)** что антикатолические погромы отличались меньшей масштабностью, они всё же имели место."

Comment: Не корректно построила предложение, да, моя вина, спасибо за все замечания и ответы. До сих пор не могу решить вопрос с отделением "тем не менее" запятой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложение исправлено:

Тем не менее, говорить о **совершенной безукоризненности  действий** протестантов не приходится: несмотря на то что антикатолические погромы отличались меньшей масштабностью, они **всё же имели место**.

Это сложное предложения с тремя предикативными основами, основы 2 и 3 входят в состав СПП. Между первой основой и СПП бессоюзная связь.

Составной союз "несмотря на то что" в первой части СПП обычно не расчленяется. Также в случае сложного состава предложения нежелательно делить придаточное на части.

Answer (score 3):

Составной союз обычно не разделяется запятой, если придаточное предложение предшествует главному ( наш пример). Однако в зависимости от смысла, логического подчеркивания придаточного предложения, наличия в предложении определенных лексических элементов сложный союз может распадаться на две части: первая входит в состав главного предложения как соотносительное слово, а вторая выполняет роль союза; в этих случаях запятая ставится только перед второй частью сочетания (т.е. перед союзом что, как, чтобы). 
***Ср.: Несмотря на то, что ветер... свободно носился над морем, тучи были неподвижны (Горький);***

Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь.Д.Э.

Answer (score 2):

Фраза чудовищная. Одна "беспрекословная безукоризненность" чего стоит. Не говоря уж о "имели место *быть*". Зачем тут это "быть"? На этом фоне "*меньшая масштабность* антикатолических погромов" — просто шедевр стиля.

Тем не менее, запятая в начале пропущена. А запятая в скобках не нужна.

Comment: Тем не менее - союз  = "однако, но", запятой не выделяется.  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_731

Comment: А вот "имели место быть" - согласна, это контаминация двух канцеляризмов: кальки с французского "имеет место" и устаревшей древнерусской формы будущего времени  "имеет быть", грустно, что эта ошибка стала появляться так часто в СМИ, что скоро, вероятно, и в словари войдёт как отдельный канцелярский оборот. Теряется культура речи.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в приведённом примере, где с подчинительного составного союза начинается новое предложение, мы можем говорить о

***нерасчленении союза в абсолютном начале предложения***.

Грамота.ру приводит какой-то [пример из Григоровича](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_483), с которым не могу согласиться.

Comment: Галина, справочники допускают такое членение.

Comment: Ай, Серж, чем этот союз лучше/хуже других нечленимых! В абсолютном-то начале!

Comment: В абсолютном начале союз, конечно, не расчленяется. Но читайте мой ответ. Я же не придумываю из себя. Об этом свидетельствуют примеры из худ. лит.

Comment: То Григорович, то Горький; на самом-то деле работа корректора.

Comment: Галина, Вы считаете, составители справочников, в данном случае Розенталь и другие, не знают такие вещи? Значит, они опираются на оригинал.

Comment: Я задам это вопрос  составителям современных учебников на Большом Вопросе. Потом отчитаюсь.

Comment: А он известные авторы?